# Avoid duplicated code in XML serializable classes

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, dry

I have two `Serializable` classes with very similar code. Actually, except for the part where specific constructor is called, serialization code is identical.

Is there a way to create a common class to contain the common parts, so that specific classes (subclasses?) can implement only the constructor part? I can think of generics, factory pattern, but could not figure out how to do it.

```
// Fictitious classes

[Serializable]
public class FlightParameters {

    public double MaxHeight { get; set; }
    pulbic double MaxSpeedKmPerHour { get; set; }

    public static FlightParameters Load(String fname) {
        FlightParameters result;
        using (var fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FlightParameters));
            try {
                result = (FlightParameters)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
            }
            // catch "file not found"
            catch (InvalidOperationException) {
                result = new FlightParameters() {
                    MaxHeight = 30000;
                    MaxSpeedKmPerHour = 1500;
                }
                serializer.Serialize(fs, result);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

}


[Serializable]
public class SailingParameters {

    public double MaxDepth { get; set; }
    pulbic double MaxSpeedKnots { get; set; }

    public static SailingParameters Load(String fname) {
        SailingParameters result;
        using (var fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SailingParameters));
            try {
                result = (SailingParameters)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
            }
            // catch "file not found"
            catch (InvalidOperationException) {
                result = new SailingParameters() {
                    MaxDepth = 13000;
                    MaxSpeedKnots = 15;
                }
                serializer.Serialize(fs, result);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
FlightParameters _fparam = FlightParameters.Load(somePath);
SailingParameters _sparam = SailingParameters.Load(someOtherPath);
```

Comment: You don't actually show any constructors; do you mean the `Load` method? Oh, and you don't need `[Serializable]` - `XmlSerializer` simply doesn't care about that

Comment: @MarcGravell I added usage examples. You're right, there are not public constructors, but you can see default constructors being called inside the "catch" block. I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing here, so any suggestion is welcome, including another completely different way of doing this.

Comment: `OpenOrCreate` could be very harmful too, note - that could litter your disk with empty files, no?

Comment: @MarcGravell possibly yes, but there are some cleanup routines running elsewhere in my program. For this specific part, I believe `OpenOrCreate` is the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can see to do that would be something like:

```
static class XmlUtils {
    public static T Load<T>(string filename, Func<T> onMissing = null)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filename)) {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            try {
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
            } catch (InvalidOperationException) { // catch "file not found"
                return onMissing == null ? new T() : onMissing();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

allowing something like;

```
public static SailingParameters Load(string filename) {
    return XmlUtils.Load<SailingParameters>(filename, () => new SailingParameters {
        MaxDepth = 13000;
        MaxSpeedKnots = 15;
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Gonna test it after lunchtime and post some feedback!

Comment: @heltonbiker you might not even need the `<SailingParameters>` - I suspect the compiler can infer that from the lambda - so `return XmlUtils.Load(filename, () => new SailingParameters {...});`

Comment: There's one problem here: my original code, inside the catch parameter, creates a new default object AND SERIALIZES IT before returning it. If I return a function that returns an object, how can I serialize it to file before returning it? It's important that it happens in `XmlUtils` class to keep avoiding duplication.

Comment: @helton k - just catch the created object instead of returning it; serialize; then return